# CSS for aligning image in the center

Tags: css, wordpress

I have an image placed in a widget on my WordPress blog. I want the image to be centered since it's smaller than the sidebar it is placed in.

I currently use the following code:

```
<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 150px; height: 155px;" src="path">
```

But the image aligns left.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: [It is probably something else that is causing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/ummwk84q/)

Comment: are there any `text-align:left` or `float:left` that might be affecting it

Comment: I don't use WordPress, but check that image does not inherits `float:left` from another rule previously defined.

Comment: Post a link to the webpage with the problem that you're having.

Comment: The (non)working example would be greatly appreciated as Ionut mentioned, on itself, the css should work, as demonstrated by potashin's fiddle. Things that could be interfering are inherited stylings or global css, both of these are very easy to check if we have a working example

Comment: Here's one of the links where it's not working, but it's basically the same on every other post page - travelersuniverse.com/places-to-visit-in-japan-for-animal-lovers.

Comment: Hey, @Laura, I posted an answer. Is that helpful ?!

Comment: @Laura accept/mark the answer correct which solved your issue by clicking on right symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try `margin: 0 auto` instead of declaring them separately. Also you can try adding `text-align: center` to to it's container or parent div

Answer (score 1):

Because everybody has added the answers using something similar. I decided to share this with everyone. You can use this solution for image in center for both `x (horizontal)` and `y (vertical)` axis **because that is what question title says**. This relays on [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```
<div id="imageBox">
  <img src="my-image.png" alt="some text" />
</div>
```

#### Using [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
#imageBox
{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:center; 
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

#imageBox img
{
    margin: 0 auto;  /* this is where magic will happen!! */
}
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/seheco/edit?css,output) of above approach.

> If you want to center **only horizontally** using `flexbox` just omit styles for `img` and set the following.

```
#imageBox
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;  /* changed from column to row  */
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Notice i have changed `flex-direction` property from `column` to `row` which is default. If you do not specify it will still work. Setting it to `column` will make it center vertically.

**There are some things that should be kept in mind with while working with flexbox.**

- [flexbox is not supported in older IE versions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) i.e. IE < 11 and has limited support for IE-10.
- The parent container (`#imgBox` in this case) should have some height and width otherwise the image will not center in one of the axis. This is also required for margin: 0 auto to work i.e. without some having `width` (not in percentage), the `margin: 0 auto` property will not work in `CSS`.

#### Alternative approach:

If you do want to rely on flexbox then it is again not much difficult. Images are `inline` in nature on web pages but they still can have `width` and `height` so they can be centered horizontally using `text-align` property i.e. using the above example...

```
#imageBox 
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

However it will not center the `img` vertically. `Vertical-align` alone will not center the image vertically in this case. For that you can [check this post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div) It is nicely explained there.

You can also use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` and apply `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` on `table-cell` to center the content on both axis but i would not recommend these unless really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two solutions

1. you must give parent div tag width:as required, i.e 75 % to 100%.
   Write css for img tag: `margin-left:250px` or more.
2. add below css for image `position relative; margin-left: 250px` or more;

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align: center;` on your div that is containing the image:

```css
.siteorigin-widget-tinymce.textwidget{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the correct WP specific CSS in your child-theme, try this:

```
<img src="path_to_image_copied_from_media_library" alt="an_alt_label" width="150" height="150" class="aligncenter size-thumbnail" />
```

size-thumbnail allows you to use the default stylings for the registered thumb-nail sized image. If you start adding CSS rules for individual images, you tend to mess up the consistency of style for the whole site.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoWvG.png)

```
<div id="imageBoxColor">
  <img src="./car.jpg" alt="some text" />
</div>

      #imageBoxColor{
     height: 100vh;
     background-color: rgb(198, 203, 202);
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
  }

  #imageBoxColor img{
     width: 400px;
     height: 400px;   
  }
```

Follow this code to align the image center. I hope your problem is solved